# Identifying failed hard drive in RAID

Tags: raid, storage, hard-drive, sun

I have a server which is running customized version of Debian. It is attached a sun storage raid. It has very limited tools and installing new tools is not allowed. :(

This message I see in `dmesg`:

```
end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 556782970
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=0x10 driverbyte=0x08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  ASC=0x44 ASCQ=0x0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 21 2f d5 7a 00 00 08 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 556782970
```

So it seems there is badblock in sector 556782970, but I don't know which hard drive it belongs to so that I can get it replaced.

- `arcconf getlogs` command does not reveal any issues with drives.
- I did `arcconf task start 1 logicaldrive 0 verify_fix` but this didn't help.
- I did an `e2fsck` check. It attempts to fix some inodes but above issue remained. (I assume since its physical issue).

more info: http://pastebin.com/cJ2bUywj

Tools not available :(
smartctl
badblocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually use arcconf you can see physical drive status like this:

```
arcconf getconfig 1 PD
```

Look for drives with Failed state to identify drives that have been marked as failed. For your reference the output would look something like this:

> ```
>   Device #6
>      Device is a Hard drive
>      State                              : Failed
>      Block Size                         : Unknown
>      Supported                          : Yes
>      Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,15(15:0)
>      Vendor                             : *MISSING*
>      Model                              : 
>      Firmware                           : 
>      Total Size                         : 0 MB
>      Write Cache                        : Unknown
>      FRU                                : None
>      S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
>      S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
>      SSD                                : No
>      MaxCache Capable                   : No
>      MaxCache Assigned                  : No
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 556782970` line, I assume that /dev/sda is the trouble child.  You can find the serial number of that device using:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep "sda$"
```

Comment: sda is a volume spanning multiple drives. I understand its having issue but I am trying to find which particular drive to replace. Also, I have dont have folder /dev/disk

Answer (score 1):

While there might be an answer that gets you the info in the OS, odds are the controller firmware can tell you if you access it during boot.

Another thing I noticed in your cut and paste is that your battery says "failed".  I wonder if the stripes are reporting failure because the Write Cache battery is toast? Though it reporting and actual bad inode would probably mean you have two problems.

Though my experience with Adaptec Controllers typically when the battery dies, it disables write caching as a preemptive measure.

Comment: I manually disabled write caching when battery had died.

Comment: I figured as much,  some of their controller do it automatically when the battery is no longer usable too.  Did you figure out which drive is having the issue?